# laravel ajax 404 page not found

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, laravel-5

trying to send post request using AngularJS in Laravel, I'm having this error message:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
app.controller('main',['$scope','$http','$httpParamSerializerJQLike',function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
 $scope.courses = [];
  $http({
    url: "/afil",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"},
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike()
}).success(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  // $scope.courses = res;
}).error(function(res) {
});
}]);
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/afil', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your form action url is correct , if you are using a group prefix in you routes don't forget to include it in the form action url

Answer (score 0):

Might be you will have to first set the header in angular module. Then you will make the http request.

```
var app = angular.module('App', [], ['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //Setting headers
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
}]);

app.controller('main',['$scope','$http','$httpParamSerializerJQLike',function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
 $scope.courses = [];
  $http({
    url: "/afil",
    method: "POST",
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike()
}).success(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  // $scope.courses = res;
}).error(function(res) {
});
}]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Burawi

Please note that :

When doing AJAX calls, the X-Requested-With header is often set to XMLHttpRequest. Laravel's Request::ajax() method is built on top of a Symfony2 method that simply checks for the presence of this header. In October 2012, Angular.js removed this header because they felt that it was rarely used.

You need to set the X-Requested-With parameter in Angular

`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"`

For more details read [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-doesnt-behave-to-angularjs-like-ajax-request)